# Nondegenerate representation vs faithful representation

Tags: representation-theory

There are two kinds of injection in the representation theory, nondegenerate representation and faithful representation. Does any relation between them?  I want to get some good examples to distinguish them, which is one kind but not the other.

You can choose group representation or C*-algebra representation to answer it, in fact, I care more about the representation for C*-algebras than groups.

Comment: So, what's the definition of "nondegenerate representation"?

Comment: Nondegenerate representation means a representation f: A→B（H）such that f(a)h=0 for any a∈A imply h=0.

Answer (score 0):

Every $C^*$ algebra admit a faithful non degenerate representation.
Let $A$ be a  subalgebra of $B(H)$ which is  counted as a faithful representation.
If $A$ is not a  non degenerate subalgebra then it has a kernel $N\subset H$ then $N^{\perp}$ is invaeriant under $A$ hence $A$ is represented on $N^{\perp}$ faitfully and nondegenerately.